# Download File from Database

Tags: php, download

With the database connected properly, when I try to download the files, the contents I get is a php page of this file which I am working on. Instead of the file which was uploaded to the database. Why is this happening?

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM docu";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed');

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
    echo "Database is empty <br>";
}
else{
    while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<a href='download.php?id='$id>$name</a><br>";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id    = $_GET['id'];   
    $query = "SELECT id, name, type, size, content FROM docu WHERE id = '$id'";       
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed');
    list($id, $name, $type, $size, $content) =  mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$name'");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-length: $size");
    echo $content;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You can't have an echo AND a header. Plus, your query may have failed.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: You're also querying twice with the same variable. Show us what the db schema is and the row contents. If your column is not BLOB, file must exists on your server.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i've tried using those error reporting codes. there are no errors yet I cannot have my document files downloaded. I have id, name, type, size, date, content and status in my table

Comment: 'id' int(11) not null auto_increment, 
'name' varchar(30) not null,
'type' varchar(30) not null,
'size' int(11) not null,
'date' datetime not null,
'content' blob not null,
'status' binary(0) not null,
primary key ('id')

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code

```
while ( (list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){echo $name . " " . $id. " " ."<a href=download.php?id=$id>$name</a><br>";  }
```

in download.php use

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id    = $_GET['id'];   
$query = "SELECT id, name, type, size, content FROM docu WHERE id = '$id'";  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);$size = $size;$type = $type;$name =$name;header("Content-length: $size");header("Content-type: $type");header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");}mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: `$row['area_of_exp']` you're assuming OP has a row called `area_of_exp`, why?